# Facebook graph api returns photo link that expires after some period

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook graph api to get page cover url.
I'm using the query like GET /v2.3/{page-id}. It returns structure like:

```
{...
    "cover": {...
        "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/..."
    }
...
}
```

Recently I have discovered that this link returned error:
"An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.1d0adfad.1428868729.19b3c7d5."
What does this error mean? Did anybody get the same error?

The link: [https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/1004859_section.10152218387031749_948700280_n.jpg?oh=cb66f8cd74647137cafcd8b305567c14&oe=54C00B8E&**gda**=1421781046_ba46001e1912f7bd322627bc5592a6f1](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/1004859_section.10152218387031749_948700280_n.jpg?oh=cb66f8cd74647137cafcd8b305567c14&oe=54C00B8E&__gda__=1421781046_ba46001e1912f7bd322627bc5592a6f1)

Comment: That is by design. It is a CDN url that stops working after a while. You need to do a new API call to get a url that works again

Comment: Thank you for response. Do you know a way to predict when the link would stop working?